# Connecting SQL Developer 1.5.4 to tnsnames.ora

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, tnsnames

I am having trouble establishing connections with tnsnames.ora while using SQL Developer 1.5.4. I have looked at other threads on this site and they have told me to go to Tools> Preferences > Database > Advanced > tnsnames directory. However I am missing the option to connect to tns directory and I am getting the option "Advanced Parameters" instead of just "Advanced". Does any body know where to find this option on SQL Developer 1.5.4? Sorry but it won't let me post an image.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks 
Niall

Comment: See this link http://theitbros.com/sql-developer-use-tnsnames-ora-file/

Comment: I have to ask... Why dont you use a newer version? It's free to use, you dont have to install it and the newest version is 4.0.3...

Comment: Hello @NMS, please share the solution if you have found one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. At my work, the DBAs years ago started keeping the current TNSNAMES.ORA on a network share, but we still had to maintain local versions for people using SQL Developer until relatively recently. To be honest, I don't remember which version the option was introduced to select a directory, but I would be quite confident it was later than the version you're on. As JaMaBing says, it's free and you don't need to install it, so why not upgrade anyway?

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I managed to get this issue resolved.